# Obtain names of variable arguments based on dot dot dot in function R (deparse)

Tags: r

I am creating an automated plotter, based on some dummy variables. I set it up such that:

```
plotter <- function(...) { }
```

will plot all the dummies I feed it.

However, I would like it to be able to add labels to the plot, namely the variable names.
I do know that

```
deparse(substitute(variablename))
```

will yield

```
"variablename"
```

which is a start, but how do I do this in the case of multiple arguments? Is it at possible? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I think this would be improved if you gave a concrete example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`names(list(...))` will get you a character vector containing the names of the supplied arguments that have been absorbed by `...`:

```
plotter <- function(...) {names(list(...))}
plotter(x=1:4, y=11:14)
# [1] "x" "y"
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to pass in unnamed arguments, try this (which extends @baptiste's now-deleted answer):

```
plotter <- function(..., pch=16, col="red") {
    nms <- setdiff(as.character(match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)), 
                   as.character(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)))
    nms
}

x <- 1:4
y <- 1:14
plotter(x, y, col="green")
# [1] "x" "y"
```

Comment: However, I here do have to assign them names. It will look a bit silly to have to call `plotter(longvarname=longvarname)`, there is no way to just have it interpret on its own without having to add the names explicitly?

Comment: @Dualinity - try `names(llist(...))` (it's in library `Hmisc`)

Comment: `[1] "..." NA`, when given 2 arguments.

Comment: @Dualinity -- The basic idea would then be `sapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], as.character)`. Will add a slightly more refined version of that to my answer.

Comment: @Dualinity, yeah, that's weird, it works outside of a function - must be some kind of environment issue

Comment: Thanks a lot of the effort, really curious if it'll be possible!

Comment: I don't think you need the `sapply` though, I think `as.character(match.call()[-1])` will be sufficient.

Comment: @Dualinity - the underlying function of `llist` works - try `as.character(sys.call())[-1]`