# R: variable name to string

Tags: string, r, variables

There are simple solutions such as:

```
> deparse(substitute(data))
[1] "data"
```

But it does not quite work when I want to extract name from a list:

```
> deparse(substitute(names(data)[1]))
[1] "names(data)[1]"
```

So the problem is that I want this as a general solution for every variable in a list/data frame/numeric that I feed into some function. And I want to see names of those variables as column names for output data frame.

Such as:

```
foo <- function(...) { 
   data <- list(...)
## some magic here ##
   names(output_df) <- ?? 
   output_df
}
```

And keep in mind that some numerics that are fed into ... don't come with names attribute. This is probably the whole reason why I want to use their environment name as column name in output data frame.

Comment: Flesh this out a bit. It's hard to understand *exactly* what you are trying to achieve. Literally do a very simple worked example with some made up data.... e.g. `data <- list( "hello" , "world" )` or whatever

Comment: It is fairly simple. Input data that is pulled into function doesn't always have names attribute. But the names of variables themselves are informative enough to help with that. So what I want is to extract variable names as vector of strings that will be later applied as names attribute to output data frame.

Comment: Right. Ok. So give an example... I assume you want this answered.

Comment: Are you looking for the `name()` function ? If you don't, you should provide an example, as Simon says.

Comment: Is this the "magic" you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819275/obtain-names-of-variable-arguments-based-on-dot-dot-dot-in-function-r-deparse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently, the "??" in question above should be substituted with:

```
setdiff(as.character(match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)), 
        as.character(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)))
```

With fully expanded example:

```
num_vec <- as.numeric(1:10)
list1 <- 1:10
list2 <- 11:20
list_data <- list(list1, list2)
df_data <- data.frame(list1, list2)

foo <- function(...) {
  input_list <- list(...)
  name_vec <- setdiff(as.character(match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)), 
                      as.character(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)))
  output_df <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(input_list)) {
    output_df <- c(output_df, input_list[i])
  }
  output_df <- data.frame(output_df)
  names(output_df) <- name_vec
  output_df
}

foo(num_vec, list_data[[1]], df_data[[1]], df_data$list2)

   num_vec list_data[[1]] df_data[[1]] df_data$list2
1        1              1            1            11
2        2              2            2            12
3        3              3            3            13
4        4              4            4            14
5        5              5            5            15
6        6              6            6            16
7        7              7            7            17
8        8              8            8            18
9        9              9            9            19
10      10             10           10            20
```

This was my intention - get data from any sort of source, do some manipulations with it (not shown in the example as it is not related to the problem) and get a data frame as an output with column names exactly as they appear in function as variables.

Thanks to Peyton for pointing out the solution in [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819275/obtain-names-of-variable-arguments-based-on-dot-dot-dot-in-function-r-deparse) which I failed to find through the search.